# Python - variable not updating in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve the ['Love-Letter' mystery problem of HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-love-letter-mystery) using Python, but I am stuck at a place where in my loop a variable is not getting updated.

```
s = input()
first_char = s[0]
last_char = s[-1]
ascii_first_char = ord(first_char)
ascii_last_char = ord(last_char)
count = 0
i = 1
while ascii_first_char < ascii_last_char:
    count += abs((ascii_last_char-ascii_first_char))
    ascii_first_char = ord(s[i])
    ascii_last_char = ord(s[-i])
    i += 1

print(count)
```

If you try to run that, you would see that alc is not changing it's value according to `ord(s[i])` where I keeps incrementing. Why is that happening?

Comment: Is this your actual code? The line `alc = ord(s[-i)])` has unmatched parentheses, so it should crash with a SyntaxError.

Comment: Yeah, i fixed that, now what?

Comment: you should give your variables more speaking names. This is quite hard for an outsider to read...

Comment: @k-nut done. DO you know the mistake?

Comment: It is updating just fine for mw, though the first two prints will show the same value because you're accessing the last index twice.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary how would i fix this?

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui That's for you to find out since you're the one solving the problem. We should only push you in the right direction if you're stuck. In addition to that, you code doesn't handle the case where `ascii_first_char > ascii_last_char`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev it does not matter as I am converting the value to absolute.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui try e.g. `mac` as input...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the first letter with s[0] and the last with s[-1]. In your loop you take the next letters with the same index i.

I don't understand your condition in the while loop. Instead of "ascii_first_char < ascii_last_char" you should test if you have looked at every element of the string. For that we have to loop len(s)/2 times. Something like:

```
while i < len(s) - i:
```

or equivalent

```
while 2*i < len(s):
```

And this conditions only work for even length. I prefer for-loops when I know how many times I will loop

```
current_line = input()
# if length is even, we don't care about the letter in the middle
# abcde <-- just need to look for first and last 2 values
# 5 // 2 == 2
half_length = len(current_line) // 2
changes = 0
for i in range(index):
    changes += abs(
        ord(current_line[i]) - ord(current_line[-(i+1)])
    )
print (changes)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = ['abc','abcba','abcd','cba']
for s in s1:
    count = 0
    i = 0
    j = -1
    median = len(s)/2
    if median == 1:
        count += abs(ord(s[0])-ord(s[-1]))
    else:
        while i < len(s)/2:
            count += abs(ord(s[j])-ord(s[i]))
            i += 1
            j -= 1
    print(count)
```